# git -C command bug

Tags: git, command

I don't know if this is the expected phenomenon of git but I think I may have found a strange bug.

I have a script that copies file from specific commit to another location

example

```
git -C C:\Users\testDir show ${hash of the commit}:test.csv > C:\Users\anotherTestDir\test.csv
```

This works as expected EXCEPT when I only have one commit.

When I have a single commit, it makes `system cannot find the file specified` error.

After I do another commit and run exact same command, it works perfectly.

Even stranger phenomenon is that when I only have one commit and use relative path, it works

example

```
git -C .\ show ${hash of the commit}:test.csv > .\test.csv
```

Is this an expected behaviour? If it is, what would be the solution to be able to use the same command when there's only one commit?

Windows CMD

[image]

Webstorm console
[image]

Comment: What if you test just `git -C C:\Users\testDir show ${hash of the commit}:test.csv` with one commit? Do you have the same error? Would be nice to have exactly the output.

Comment: you mean just show without copy right? Yes same error. Very strange @gsi-frank. Try it yourself I am very intrigued

Comment: Can you test `git -C C:/Users/testDir show ${hash of the commit}:test.csv` and if not work then `git -C "C:/Users/testDir" show ${hash of the commit}:test.csv` ? Worked for me in OSX, so I guess that is a windows-shell-git character scape thing.

Comment: Works fine for me on windows in `cmd.exe` with `git` version `2.14.1.windows.1`

Comment: fine on windows with git bash as well

Comment: I have updated my pictures. It was indeed about the slash direction for Git Bash but still the same execution doesn't work on the script for some reason. @gsi-frank @Anthony Sottile @LightBender. I am using `path.resolve()` to get the file path for the command

Comment: They are different names but they are all in the same folder

Comment: Could you confirm that you already have a command construct that works? One thing is to have a command working and another the script that constructs it correctly. I would have to see the script that you are using to generate the command and execute it, maybe that could be material for another question ;)

Comment: @gsi-frank I am running the same command but works above and doesn't below

Comment: I'm kind of lost here. The command with `/` worked or not? Would be nice edit your question accord ;)

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments: use `C:/Users/testDir` instead of `C:\Users\testDir` as parameter.